# .war file with jar file and websphere shared library jar file

Tags: java, jar, websphere, war

I have a war file with an embedded jar file on it (sample.jar) and at the same time I have defined a shared library on webpshere with the same jar file (sample.jar), which one is going to be used by the war file? Is it the one inside the war file or the one that is defined on the webpshere shared lirarby?

I appreciate all answers.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Websphere Shared Libraries "Priority"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989869/websphere-shared-libraries-priority)

Comment: Well, I have to agree :-).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on classloader policy setting (parent first or local first).